# FileReader (probably) doing crazy stuff after calling a 2nd time

Tags: android, file, filereader, filewriter

My App is writing data into a txt-file. (the code was on here some time ago for another reason)

Im always reading the whole file into a String Array and replacing an explicit line.

After reading the File I log the Data to observe it. My main is calling the App 7 times (for each line) but after the first call the data im logging is just weird.

Here is my code:

```
 public void writeFileData(String data, int line) {

    String[] lines = new String[999];
    File file = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    OutputStreamWriter os = null;

    try {


        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "data.txt");

        if(!file.exists())
        {
            try
            {
                if(file.createNewFile())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, "File was created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log.e("Error creating file", ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        int i = 0;
        while(i < 7)
        {
            buffer = br.readLine();

            lines[i] = buffer;
            i++;
        }

        br.close();

        fos = new FileOutputStream(file, false);

        lines[line] = data;

        for(i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            if (lines[i].isEmpty())
            {
                Log.e(TAG, i + "is empty");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e(TAG, lines[i]);
            }
        }

        for(i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            try {
                fos.write(lines[0].getBytes());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.e("Error writing", ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        try
        {
            fos.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("Error closing/flushing", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("Error creating streams", ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

**[My logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9TP8.png)**

The calls inside the main look like:

```
    writeFullData();           
    writeFileData("001",0);
    writeFileData("002",1);
    writeFileData("110",2);
    writeFileData("110",3);
    writeFileData("110",4);
    writeFileData("110",5);
    writeFileData("110",6);
```

*writeFullData();* is writing into the txt file (visible in the logcat image)

Thanks in advance.

Xaver Seiringer

Comment: can you post your txt data?

Comment: It is empty, but it sure wasn't while reading as we can see in the logcat. It's like im writing null into the file

Comment: in this case, i guess it reading more that you actually have, change the for, to 4, check what it print, then change to 5 and so on.

Comment: Yeah that could be, I'll try it and edit in case it doesnt work that way.Thanks

Comment: Ok i think i know whats the problem. My Reader isnt starting at line 1 when reading the after the 2nd call. How can I change that?

Comment: check if you have some special character in the file, by the way, you are using it fine.

Comment: I got no idea what could be wrong...

Comment: Ok i got it. I was lookin at the wrong file (manually). I mixed up a true and false with overwriting (FileWriter). Its working now! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I called a function overwriting the whole file. That way i was able to overwatch every single line and Log the input so i will notice a change in the lines and my *writeFileData()* Function also had to read something.
I didnt write false in the FileWriter!

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
```

I wrote 21 lines into the file instead of 7 (after calling 4 times).

The 2nd mistake was i forgot to bw.newLine in *writeFileData*.

Those mistakes doe...

But thanks for the help.